# Why use a nested class to implement Comparator?

Tags: java, comparator, comparable

Going through docjar for `String`, I happened to see the following piece of code:

```
public static final Comparator<String> CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER
                                         = new CaseInsensitiveComparator();

private static class CaseInsensitiveComparator
                       implements Comparator<String>, java.io.Serializable {
    // use serialVersionUID from JDK 1.2.2 for interoperability
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 8575799808933029326L;

    public int compare(String s1, String s2) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

My question is, why can't we just implement `Comparator`, like `Comparable`, and use a private method rather than a nested class?

Also on a side note, why doesn't `Comparator` have a method with a single parameter similar to `compareTo` in `Comparable`?

Comment: You can. Not a real question. But it usually doesn't make sense for a class to implement its own Comparator method. Comparators are used when you have two 'foreign' objects.

Comment: @EJP - in other words, you can ... but it is a daft idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My question is why cannot we just implement comparator, just like comparable and use a private function rather than inner class ?

Well (pretty much) the whole point of the `Comparator` interface is that an implementation of the interface is a separate class to the class of the objects being compared.

In theory you could do what you are suggesting, but the net result is counter-intuitive

```
public class MyKey implements Comparator<MyKey> {
    private String field;

    public boolean compare(MyKey m1, MyKey m2) {
        // We must ignore this.field!  We are comparing m1 and m2 ...
        return m1.field.compareTo(m2.field);
    }
}

MyKey[] keys = ...
Arrays.sort(keys, new MyKey());  // Note we have to pass an instance
                                 // to provide the Comparator.
```

In addition to being a bit counter-intuitive, your idea is limited in the sense that `MyKey` can only "provide" one comparator this way.

Frankly, if you are going to do this, it *makes more sense* to have `MyKey` implement `Comparable<MyKey>`.

---

Suppose that they had implemented `String` the way you proposed.  Then this ...

```
   String[] strings = new String[]{"a", "c", "B"};
   Arrays.sort(strings);
```

... means sort case sensitive, but ...

```
   String[] strings = new String[]{"a", "c", "B"};
   Arrays.sort(strings, "weasel");
```

... would mean sort case insensitive.  Does that *really* strike you as a good idea?  **Really?**

Answer (score 6):

Because a `String` **is not** a `Comparator`. Sure, they are indeed `Comparable`, but they are not "comparison functions"<sup>1</sup> themselves: it makes no sense to have `String` implement `Comparator`.

On the other hand, `CaseInsensitiveComparator` **is** a specific comparison function, only pertaining to strings. So, it is declared as a `static` nested class.

---

<sup>1</sup> See [`Comparator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can only implement one interface of the same type. String already implements Comparable for lexicographical comparison:

```
public final class String
    implements java.io.Serializable, Comparable<String>, CharSequence
{
```

But it needs more `compareTo` method (eg: to perform case insensitive comparison). Following would give you compiler error:

```
public final class String
    implements java.io.Serializable, Comparable<String>, Comparable<String>, CharSequence
{
```

Hence this is probably one reason it has additional comparator.

The idea of comparator is an object that provide comparison service between two items, not a contract where one is comparable to another (comparable interface)

Implementing Comparator on a String will compile, but this will be *semantically wrong*

```
public final class String
    implements java.io.Serializable, Comparable<String>, Comparator<String>, CharSequence
{
```

Comment: I think I misunderstood earlier, now I get the gist of what you're trying to say. However, from a compilation standpoint, there is no reason why `String` couldn't implement both `Comparator` and `Comparable`.

Comment: Agreed, but implementing Comparator on String will be wrong semantically (meaning / purpose-wise)

Answer (score 0):

Having this be a class rather than a function allows us to polymorphically apply different comparison strategies to Collections (or other classes which may be performing comparisons).  This way the method using the comparator doesn't need to know whether it's a case-sensitive comparator or a case-insensitive comparator or something else; it just performs the comparison. If this were a function however, such polymorphism would not apply. The method performing the comparison would either have to use "the" comparison method, or would have to know what kind of comparison was being performed, in order to select the correct method.

Having two parameters rather than tying the first parameter to one particular String allows us to use the same comparator on any number of Strings. Otherwise we'd have to keep track of a lot of comparators when dealing with large collections. It also allows usage of this comparator with either a subclass on either the left side or the right side (or both); with just one parameter there would not be that flexibility.

Answer (score 0):

The primary reason is to expose the `Comparator` object for things like [`TreeMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html), where `String`s can be used as keys, or other objects where ordering or a different kind of equality is useful. It can't be a `static` method since the `Comparator` interface can't specify a `static` method and the `Comparator` has to be an object that implements the interface to be used in classes like `TreeMap`. We need a separate one that's case insensitive because the default comparison (implemented by `Comparable`'s methods) is already taken by the case sensitive comparison.

Answer (score 0):

> why cannot we just implement comparator, just like comparable and use
>   a private function rather than inner class

[String class](http://www.docjar.org/html/api/java/lang/String.java.html) implements `Comparable<String>` interface, which is used to compare two strings lexicographically, which is a pretty common way to compare two strings.

However, sometimes you need to compare two strings in different way, for example comparing them while ignoring case sensitivity. [`Comparator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) interface provides a way to compare two objects differently. In this case, `CaseInsensitiveComparator` is implemented to provide this capability and is used in `String.compareToIgnoreCase()` method.